# Legends/Labels for DonutChart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Iam using Donut chart iam able to show the  chart with my data but iam not able to show the legends or labels when i use the area chart iam able to show the legend by following the sample in telerik for kendoui website  but for donut chart im not getting legends can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding kendo-chart-legend inside kendo-chart like this-

```
 <kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="true"></kendo-chart-legend>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="donut" [data]="[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Comment: iam using this <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="true"></kendo-chart-legend>

Comment: yes for my bar chart also its working for donut chart its not working

Comment: <kendo-chart>
          <kendo-chart-title text="Simple Donut Chart">
          </kendo-chart-title>
          <kendo-chart-series-defaults type="donut">
          </kendo-chart-series-defaults>
          <kendo-chart-legend position="top">
          </kendo-chart-legend>
          <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="seriesData">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
          </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
    `

class AppComponent {
    private seriesData = [[4,"1st"],[7,"2nd"],[5,"3rd"]];
}

Comment: above is working for me i gave the data input wrong earlier now its working for me

Comment: yes, you need to give 2-d array in case of pie or donut